# Read 3D array and plot it as 2D like a picture without converting from 3D to 2D like np.concatenate

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, numpy-ndarray, imshow

```
x = np.array[[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[8, 4, 1, 0, 0],
              [6, 8, 5, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[2, 4, 0, 2, 3],
              [2, 5, 5, 3, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]],

             [[4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]]
```

I want to get an image from this `NumPy` file with the `imshow()` command of the `matplotlib` library but I shouldn't convert it to 3d array. Is there any way to read 3D array and plot it as 2D like this picture.

[image]

If I couldn't explain, I normally need to convert the array we have to 2D and draw it. Normally I can use commands like `np.concatenate` or `np.append` for this and get the following array.

```
x = np.array[[[8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

But I need to draw it without converting it to 2D.

Comment: A "representative" plot is not helpful.  What Is it that you want to plot?  Points?  Lines?  What will you be showing?   You have a (4,3,5) array there.  How would you map that to a plot?

Comment: As I wrote, I will add together the 3rd dimensions in the array to get a two-dimensional array.

Comment: You can't get that plot without converting it to a 2D array.

Comment: Most NumPy methods will not change the original array; if you want to use methods that do, you can run `.copy()` to make a clone of the original, reformat it into the 2D version you need, and plot this.

Comment: I see you have accepted my answer, but I have to say that, even if there is no explicit copying using  `concatenate` etc, the **data is copied**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image

[image]
depicts a 3 rows × 20 columns array and you start with a `(4,3,5)` shape, and from the 2D array you've printed

```
x = np.array([[8, 7, 1, 0, 3, 8, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 4, 0, 2, 3, 4, 7, 2, 8, 0],
              [2, 8, 5, 5, 2, 6, 8, 5, 5, 2, 2, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2],
              [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I see that you need to concatenate 4 matrices with 3 rows and 5 columns, hence the last dimension must stay untouched while the first two axes must be swapped, so I think the right incantation would be

```
...
plt.imshow(np.transpose(x, (1,0,2)).reshape(3,20))
...
```

that gives me

[image]